# Add all values in an array JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
<div id="timeCalac">Click me to calculate your average time</div>
```

```js
myData = [34, 67, 78];
var arrayTotalValue = 0;

$("#timeCalac").click(function () {
    // arrayTotalValue = add value of myData array function
    arrayTotalValue = arrayTotalValue/myData.length;
    $("#timeCalac").html(arrayTotalValue);    
});
```

I am making a function that records how long it took for the user to click on a element
I then use the `.push()` command to add this number to the myData array.
Is there a JavaScript or jQuery function that can add the value of the myData array and then store it in the arrayTotalValue variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific function to sum the values of an array, however you can use `reduce()` to achieve it:

```
myData = [34, 67, 78];
var arrayTotalValue = 0;

$("#timeCalac").click(function () {
    arrayTotalValue = myData.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
    $(this).html(arrayTotalValue);    
});
```

Comment: How can I get the return value of this function then store it in my arrayTotalValue variable?

Comment: @JohnSmith that's what this *is* doing...?

Comment: How do I put it in a variable tho? I am new to all this

Comment: It is in a variable - the `arrayTotalValue` variable.

Comment: Here's a working example to hopefully make it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/sd6Lwuny/